# Put div in MYSQL die

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this mysql request:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

It´s simple, but I want to change the `mysql_error()` for this div:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0 .7em;">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Error!</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use die() for error_handling. Ever. Use exceptions, they are built into PHP, and error handling is their only reason for existing.

Comment: **mysql_* functions are deprecated**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to make function for showing errors :

```
function show_error($error_text){
    $var = '<div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0 .7em;">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>'.$error_text.'</strong></p>
        </div>
        </div>';
    die($var);
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
mysql_query($query) or show_error('Query execute failed');
```

Comment: And How Can I do this but with the text if the insert works fine. Example: use the function to show if the insert was fine like this Query OK!

Comment: In my projects you will find 3 functions, one for showing and logging error, usually called report_error, one for warnings and one for reporting success to the user, so You should make something your own.
You can contact me for more info. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the whole html code inside a variable, like so:

```
$var = '<div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 0 .7em;">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Error!</strong></p>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Then, you just have to edit the `die()` to print the `$var`.

```
mysql_query($query) or die($var);
```